# Efficient Django Query using annotate function

Tags: mysql, django, database

There is a table A with fields:

```
id_1(int)|id_2(int)
```

I have a query writen on id_2:

```
blocked_users = bl_.objects.filter(id_2=request.user.id);
#for a single value of id_2,there are multiple entries,like:
 id1|id2
 2  |3
 5  |3
 7  |3
```

There is a table B with fields:

```
id_3(int)|id4(int)
```

Now,for every **id_1** in the variable:**blocked_users**,there is a **id3**
in the table B,which I want to access:

```
table B:
id3|id4
2  |90 
5  |89
7  |87
```

I know it can be done with for loops,but is there a better solution for this(eg:by the **annotate** function)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) for getting list of `id_1` from table A.

```
blocked_users = bl_.objects.filter(id_2=request.user.id).values_list('id_1',flat=True);
```

and then query on your table to for all the rows that match to one of the `id_1` value from your blocked_users list.

```
result=B.objects.filter(id_3__in=blocked_users)
```